# VB.NET Listbox item color

Tags: vb.net, colors, items

Is there any way I can make a listbox item look like this?
I tried a code and it changed the item background color,but now I need something like this.
"(RED)Text bla bla,(green) bla bla"
I mean multiple colors on the same line?
(red) and (green) are forecolors.please help meh!

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate, since OP is asking for 2 colors on the same line of text, and the related question is different colors for each item, not the same item/line

Comment: It would be the same code with an few lines  to change colors and print the rest of the text.  it gets the OP much much closer to The Solution than they are now and gives them the chance to ask a Good Question.